# read-only file system error tryng to mkdir into a windows containing HDD from a broken laptop

Tags: directory, hard-disk, readonly

I just broke my laptop (running Windowns 10) which is the one that I use for music making. I've got another laptop without HDD and my plan was to mount the HDD into this second laptop and try to extract the files by booting kali.

I do have another PC (also Windows 10) but I dont have any external drive, so I've tried to setup a Samba server and put a folder into the HDD. But when I try to do anything instead of coping files it say to me:

```
mkdir /media/kali/HDD/shared
mkdir: cannot create directory 'shared': Read-only file system
```

I'm not sure what to do next

Comment: Why don't you just move the hard-disk from the broken laptop to the other? Job done.

Comment: i have already tried but, unfortunally it wont start, it says no bootable devices..

Comment: Did you try putting the hdd in the other pc and booting from a live usb image?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a pure hardware and / or samba problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you try mount -o remount,rw /dev/[whatever] /media/kali/HDD

Also as it is can you still read/extract files from the Windows mount into a local linux folder, or is it not letting you access them at all?

Might still need the `-t ntfs` option in `mount` too

Comment: done!!! great! thank you!

Comment: Yeah, lsblk will show you which is mounted. An alternative which is really under-sold is that you can use /dev/disk/by-id/  which contains links to the /dev/sd* devices which are named after the human-readable HDD model name, so like Kingston or Toshiba. the sd* ones can change, but those ones won't.

Comment: now i've got another problem, i cant create a directory inside the HDD
it says:
"Error creating directory /media/kali/HDD/newfolder: no such file or directory"

Comment: does `df` show the HDD mounted at /media/kali/HDD? and does `ls /media/kali/HDD` show your Windows files? `mkdir /media/kali/HDD/newfolder` should work if so. Most of the time when I see that error in `mkdir`, it's because you're trying to make more than one new folder layer at a time (if you have folder `oldfolder` for instance, you can't `mkdir oldfolder/newfolder/newfolder2`. It might be worth `umount`ing /media/kali/HDD and doing `mount -o rw -t ntfs /dev/sd[whatever] /media/kali/HDD` from scratch.